# JSONP requests from LinkedIn and StumbleUpon

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

Im trying to build an app that gets information about URL from different social networks like Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, StumbleUpon, Digg and Delicious.

I am requesting information with REST and mostly am getting JSON formatted responses. And parse them with javascript (jQuery)

I had no problems connecting to Facebook, Twitter and Delicious with jQuerys $.getJSON method using JSONP dataType (adding callback=? to the url) but problem comes with LinkedIn and StumbleUpon.

When i use same technique i am getting errors.

For StumbleUpon

```
"invalid label"

{"result":{"url":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/","in_index":true,"publicid":"2pI1xR","views":201756,"title":"Google","thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn.stumble-upon.com\/mthumb\/31\/10031.jpg","thumbnail_b":"http:\/\/cdn.stumble-upon.com\/bthumb\/31\/10031.jpg","submit_link":"http:\/\/www.stumbleupon.com\/submit?url=http:\/\/www.google.com\/","badge_link":"http:\/\/www.stumbleupon.com\/badge?url=http:\/\/www.google.com\/","info_link":"http:\/\/www.stumbleupon.com\/url\/www.google.com\/"},"timestamp":1323182766,"success":true}
```

Obviously it doesn't work without JSONP request type since its cross-domain request.  I did some research and found that problem might be that jQuery sends JSONP request but get a JSON response and then stumbles.  If that is true im not sure what should i do to make it right. I did a response test with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and got valid result. So it seems the problem is with the way i parse it not in the response itself.

For LinkedIn i get next

```
"missing ) after argument list" 
IN.Tags.Share.handleCount({"count":18118,"url":"http://www.google.com/"}
```

So obviously its invalid JSON and jQuery bugs out.  Is there any way to get that data other way?

So i am kinda stuck here as i see the results but i cant get them to parse.

PS i wouldn't want to use server side code for this.

Heres the code i use:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';

// StumbleUpon
$.getJSON("http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=" + url +"&callback=?", function (data) {                    
   console.log(data);                    
});

$.getJSON("http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share-count?url=" + url +"&callback=?", function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You can't make a JSONP request to an arbitrary web service and expect to get a result--the code you're calling must be set up properly to process JSONP requests

Comment: Could you please point me into right direction.  I am a bit confused, since i made same calls for twitter and facebook and they did work and stumbleupon and LinkedIn don't. Would really appreciate an example or some resource. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but I'm working on something similar, though not using jQuery. I've gotten LinkedIn to work using a different URL:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url={url}&format=jsonp
```

The key for me in this instance was using the `jsonp` value for format. `json` didn't work. You'll also need to include your callback function.

As for StumbleUpon, I'm getting errors too, but I'll update this answer if I find a solution.